# Exception in python unknown errors

Tags: python

```
      except ValueError:
        print "the input is Invaild(dd.mm.year)"
    except as e:
        print "Unknown error"
        print e
```

This is the code I wrote, if an error different then valueerror will happen will it print it in e? 
thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to catch the `BaseException` or `object` here to be able to assign to `e`:

```
except ValueError:
    print "the input is Invaild(dd.mm.year)"
except BaseException as e:
    print "Unknown error"
    print e
```

or, better still, `Exception`:

```
except ValueError:
    print "the input is Invaild(dd.mm.year)"
except Exception as e:
    print "Unknown error"
    print e
```

The blanket `except:` will catch the same exceptions as `BaseException`, catching just `Exception` will *ignore* `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`, and `GeneratorExit`. Not catching these there is *generally* a good idea.

For details, see the [exceptions documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).

Comment: Does `Exception` also ignore `SyntaxError`?

Comment: @SethMMorton: No, `SyntaxError` is a subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: Interesting... It seems odd to me that it would be a subclass of `Exception`, because in general I wouldn't want to catch a syntax error in a `try` statement.

Comment: @SethMMorton: During compilation the `try` doesn't apply **yet**. Only when you use `import`, `eval`, `exec` or `compile()` can you catch `SyntaxError` exceptions.

Comment: When I see that written in front of me it makes total sense.  I *would* want to catch a `SyntaxError` in an `eval` (for example) so I see the logic now.  Again, many thanks for your excellent answers!

Comment: @SethMMorton: in other words, compiling a file throws the exception, regardless of what statements are *in* the file. A `try: print(\nexcept SyntaxError: pass` won't protect you from the missing closing parenthesis. But you *can* protect other code from the exception when importing that module.

Answer (score 3):

No, that code will throw a `SyntaxError`:

If you don't know the exception your code might throw, you can capture for just [`Exception`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception).  Doing so will get all built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions:

```
except ValueError:
    print "the input is Invaild(dd.mm.year)"
except Exception as e:
    print "Unknown error"
    print e
```